# Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::isDeferred()

Tags: php, laravel-6, laravel-socialite

Hi i'm new to laravel socialite,when i run the command php artisan config:cache to update the .env file i get this error:  Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::isDeferred();

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

Using version ^5.1 for laravel/socialite
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
- Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.7.0): Loading from cache
- Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.4.0): Loading from cache
- Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.2.0): Loading from cache
- Installing league/oauth1-client (v1.8.2): Loading from cache
- Installing laravel/socialite (v5.1.0): Loading from cache
  'C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231e2c48e7a17aefd5' is not a zip archive.
  Unzip with ZipArchive class failed, falling back to unzip command
  Failed to download laravel/socialite from dist: Failed to execute (9) unzip -qq -o "C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231e2c48e7a17aefd5" -d "C:\x
  ampp\htdocs\matatu6.0/vendor/composer/5556bc2b"

[C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231e2c48e7a17aefd5]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231e2c48e7a17aefd5 or
C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231e2c48e7a17aefd5.zip, and cannot find C:\xampp\htdocs\matatu6.0\vendor/laravel/socialite/59c666443f49cf231
e2c48e7a17aefd5.ZIP, period.

```
Now trying to download from source
```

- Installing laravel/socialite (v5.1.0): Cloning 14082c6651 from cache
  guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing laminas/laminas-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
  guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing ext-intl (Required for Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) support)
  Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
  Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
  Writing lock file
  Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 149:

Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::isDeferred()

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 1):

update: upgrading from the laravel 5 way of declaring provide class in config/app, this ended up conflicting with laravel 6 package auto discovery, therefore causing even `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` not to work. removing `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class` in `config/app.php` solved this issue and re-installing the socialite package